# Why i am not able to see all the link names in a web page by using $("a")?

Tags: jquery

After using `$("a") in the Chrome console, i got the output as:

> jQuery.fn.init(2) [a, a, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "a"]

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Demo </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>jQuery Demo</h1>

<ul>
<li>CR7 <a target="_blank" href="https://ronaldo7.net">Go To Web Page</a> 
</li>
<li>LM10</li>
<li>NMJ <a target="_blank" href="https://jQuery.com"> Jquery </a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) What are you expecting instead? There are two `a` elements on that page. You're getting back a jQuery object with two `a` elements in it. So...?

Comment: `$('a')` creates a jQuery object which is what you are showing. Provide relevant code and a proper explanation of what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I didn't get the name of the links.

Answer (score 0):

`$("a")` will select all `a` tags in your page, then you have to loop through this jquery object to get attributes of each, or use [index-related selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) `$("a:eq(n)")` to get a particular one

```js
$("a").each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});


console.log("first link:",$("a:eq(0)").attr('href'));

console.log("last link:",$("a:eq("+($("a").length-1)+")").attr('href'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>jQuery Demo</h1>

<ul>
<li>CR7 <a target="_blank" href="https://ronaldo7.net">Go To Web Page</a> 
</li>
<li>LM10</li>
<li>NMJ <a target="_blank" href="https://jQuery.com"> Jquery </a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem : You want to see all the link names in a web page by using $(“a”)

> Solution :
>
> - You need to use `each()` to get this done.
> - Link name are stored in `href` attribute, for that you need to use `.attr('href')`

Please check below code:

```js
$('ul li a').each(function(e){
    console.log('Link ' + e  + ' is : ' + $(this).attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>jQuery Demo</h1>

<ul>
    <li>CR7 <a target="_blank" href="https://ronaldo7.net">Go To Web Page</a></li>
    <li>LM10</li>
    <li>NMJ <a target="_blank" href="https://jQuery.com"> Jquery </a></li>
</ul>
```